# Unable to use "page down" effectively in my crawler

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I've written a very tiny script in python in combination with selenium to make a webpage automatically scroll down to it's bottom. My script can do it only to a certain extent because I don't understand how to set the highest parameter of the range so that my script will follow that and reach the bottom of the page. I don't really have any knowledge as to how I should fix the highest range that is why I set it to 10 in my script to see whether it works. If i get any idea how to reach the bottom of that webpage using the way I started here, I would be very grateful. Thanks in advance.

Script I've tried with:

```
from selenium import webdriver ; import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://fortune.com/fortune500/list/")
sloping = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body')
for i in range(10):                        #I'was talking about this range
    sloping.send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)
    time.sleep(3)
```

Comment: Is your goal to go immediately to the bottom of a page?

Comment: Thanks IamBatman, for your comment. What made you surmise I expected that? I just need to know what should be the process without hardcoding any number to the range as I did above.

Comment: From your post..  _"If i get any idea how to reach the bottom of that webpage using the way I started here, I would be very grateful."_

Comment: So bottom of the page?

Comment: Does that mean to go there immediately?

Comment: Alright, lets not get snarky, I'm saying do you want to get to the bottom of the page without ROCKING it down the page down way.  That is what I meant by immediately.

Comment: If you need to rock it to check things as you go down the page, then I don't currently have  quick fix for you, but if your goal is to get to the bottom of a page, any size page, in one quick motion.  I may have a quick fix for you.  I just need to know what exactly you want to do.

Comment: Yes, sort of. I just came across this method `page_down` today in another thread so I thought of making use of it.

Comment: Okay I'll be very happy to have that. Please provide it as an answer so that i can accept it, if it helps. Thanks.

Comment: On your keyboard, (assuming you have a PC) if you hold the "Control" key and push "End" key it will immediately drop any page to the very bottom.  So you should hold the "keydown" sometimes "keyup" works, and then do the sendkeys with "end".  Make sense?  You can manually try it yourself first and see what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in one line by scrolling to `document.body.scrollHeight` You can try this

```
 lenOfPage = driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);var lenOfPage=document.body.scrollHeight;return lenOfPage;")
        match=False
            while(match==False):
                    lastCount = lenOfPage
                    time.sleep(3)
                    lenOfPage = driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);var lenOfPage=document.body.scrollHeight;return lenOfPage;")
                    if lastCount==lenOfPage:
                        match=True
```

- scroll down as described above
- wait a few seconds
- save the size of the page source (xxx.page_source)
- if the size of the page source is larger than the last page source size saved, loop back and scroll down some more

Comment: Thanks zsbappa, for your kind answer. I'm familiar with the answer you've provided. I've explicitly mentioned `page_down` in my title using which I want to accomplish the script. Moreover, I've mentioned again in my description saying that I wanted to solve this the way I've started. Thanks again.